# What can I do to store instances of a class and manage state in the context of a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

I’m using this Rectangle class

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(x, y, width, height, color, hasCollision = false, kills = false) {
    this.A = new Point(x, y)
    this.B = new Point(x + width, y)
    this.C = new Point(x + width, y + height)
    this.D = new Point(x, y + height)
    this.center = new Point(x + width / 2, y + height / 2)
    this.width = width
    this.height = height
    this.color = color
    this.hasCollision = hasCollision
    this.kills = kills
  }

  get vertices() {
    const { A, B, C, D } = this
    return {
      A,
      B,
      C,
      D
    }
  }

  get x() {
    return this.A.x
  }

  get y() {
    return this.A.y
  }

  static translate(rectangle, vector) {
    for (let vertice of Object.values(rectangle.vertices)) {
      vertice.translate(vector)
    }
    rectangle.center.translate(vector)
  }

  translate(vector) {
    Rectangle.translate(this, vector)
  }

  hasUserFallenInTrap(user) {
    if (circleIntersectsRectangle(user, this) && this.kills) {
      return true
    }

    return false
  }

  display(ctx, useOwnColor = true) {
    const { x, y, width, height } = this
    if (useOwnColor) {
      ctx.fillStyle = this.color
        ? this.color.hexString
        : this.kills
        ? 'red'
        : '#000000'
    }
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height)
  }
}
```

I need to store a bunch of Rectangles in an array so that I can display them in a canvas (wrapped in a React component). The component doesn’t update every frame, I’m using my own draw function on the canvas :

```
// Here is the component
class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const world = loadMap('world1')
    this.state = {
      currentWorld: world,
      users: {},
      user: new User(
        world.spawn.center.x,
        world.spawn.center.y,
        12,
        Color.random(),
        '',
        world.spawn
      )
    }
    this.canvas = React.createRef()
    this.ctx = null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { user } = this.state
    server.userConnects(user)
    openConnection()
    this.ctx = this.canvas.current.getContext('2d')
    setPointerLock(this.canvas.current, this.mouseMoved)
    this.request = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    closeConnection()
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.request)
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false
  }

  updateUserID = id => {
    this.setState({ u })
  }

  mouseMoved = event => {
    const { currentWorld, user } = this.state
    const displacement = new Vector(
      event.movementX / pixelRatio,
      event.movementY / pixelRatio
    )
    user.translate(displacement)
    resolveWorldBordersCircleCollision(user)
    for (const w of currentWorld.walls) {
      if (w.hasCollision) stepCollisionResolve(user, w)
    }
    server.updateUserPosition(user)
  }

  draw = () => {
    const { currentWorld, users, user } = this.state
    this.request = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw)
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
    this.ctx.fillText(fpsCounter.fps, 1000, 20)
    currentWorld.walls.forEach(w => {
      if (w.hasCollision && resolveCollisionCircleRectangle(user, w)) {
        server.updateUserPosition(user)
      }
      w.display(this.ctx)
    })
    currentWorld.movableWalls.forEach(w => {
      w.walkPath()
      if (w.hasCollision && resolveCollisionCircleRectangle(user, w)) {
        server.updateUserPosition(user)
      }
      w.display(this.ctx)
    })
    currentWorld.traps.forEach(t => {
      t.display(this.ctx)
      if (t.hasUserFallenInTrap(user)) {
        user.kill()
        server.updateUserPosition(user)
      }
    })
    user.display(this.ctx, false)
    Object.values(users)
      .filter(u => u.id !== user.id)
      .forEach(u => {
        u.display(this.ctx, true)
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <canvas ref={this.canvas} id="canvas" width={WIDTH} height={HEIGHT} />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

I’m not sure how I can store and manage this array of rectangles.

I’m translating a rectangle using the class method translate.

```
const rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 10, 10)
rect.translate({x: 10, y: 20})
```

But I can’t do that if the rectangle is in the state of a component.
calling `rect.translate` would mutate the state directly.

Creating a new object everytime I’m updating the state completely defeats the purpose of using this class .

using object destructuring would create a plain new object, and so I wouldn’t be able to call its `display` method anymore :

```
// changing a single rectangle for example 
const { rectangles } = this.state
this.setState({ rectangles: [...rectangles.splice(0,index) , { ...rectangles[index], x: rectangles[index].x + 10, y: rectangles[index].y + 10 }, ...rectangles.splice(index + 1)]
```

Using an array outside of any react component appears like the only solution, but not really satisfying either for a react app.

I’m out of ideas to manage the state of my applications.

Are there better ways to store this array of `Rectangle` instances?
Or using this kind of object design is simply impossible in react?

Comment: "*Creating a new object everytime I’m updating the state completely defeats the purpose of using this class*" - why? Having `translate` return a new instance sounds totally useful.

Comment: Haven’t thought of that, but I’m refreshing the canvas 60 times per second. creating a new instance everytime I’m moving a rectangle around seems really heavy performance wise.

Comment: Are you doing the animation frames yourself, or are you trying to get React to do the canvas repaints?

Comment: No I,m using my own draw function in the react component (I’ve updated the question to add it).
The component mounts, render the canvas, and then I keep painting the same canvas without updating the component

Comment: In that case, there's indeed no reason to put them in the `state` - you don't need React to look into them. Just store the array of rectangles directly on your instance, like you do with `.canvas` or `.ctx`.

Comment: You could also let the rectangles handle their own drawing depending on the use case. Like call an update method on the rectangle as the canvas is painting and let the rectangle draw/move/resize/translate if it needs to. that way the logic is more encapsulated to the purpose of the shape

Answer (score 3):

*The hard part is figuring out whether mutability is really needed (e.g. for performance reasons) or if the state can live inside React after giving it more thought (and a good night's sleep).*

If mutability is needed, that part of the app can live outside of React as an [Uncontrolled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) (the state can live in DOM or some imperative code that will update the DOM).

A parent component from React can access the out-of-react mutable state (*from event handlers or lifecycle methods*) by using a `ref` (see the article above). A simplified example, using a `useRef` hook:

```js
const rndColor = () => `rgb(${Array.from(Array(3)).map(() => Math.random()*255).join(',')})`

const App = () => {
  const canvasRef = React.useRef()
  const handleClick = () => {
    // --> rect.translate({x: 10, y: 20}) can be called here <--
    canvasRef.current.style.background = rndColor()
  }
  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} onClick={handleClick} />
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```